# Selector for NgRx root store

Tags: angular, typescript, ngrx, ngrx-store

This is my first shot to NgRx Store so get ready for newbie question...

Everything I put in place so far work but one part of my code doesn't seems "right".

My store is build with 2 interfaces (token.model.ts):

```
export interface Keyring {
  jwt: string;
  status: string;
}

export interface TokenState {
  readonly keyring: Keyring;
}
```

The store sit in the root of the app (app.module.ts):

```
...    
StoreModule.forRoot({ security: keyringReducer }),
...
```

Note here the name in the map... **security**

The selector I used to access my store in my component is like this and it work:

```
this.token$ = store.select<any>((state: any) => state.security.keyring.jwt);
```

Now, this is where it doesn't feel right since nothing is type and I want to replace it with a "clean" selector. So it tried this :

```
const selectState = (state: TokenState) => state.keyring;
export const selectJwt = createSelector(
         selectState,
         (state: Keyring) => state.jwt
       );
...

this.token$ = store.select(selectJwt);
```

And for sure, this doesn't work (state is undefined)! And I can see why, the "security" object is missing in the equation but I can't find a way to include it in the declaration of my selector. It's not part of my interface and just a literal in the registration of my store.

So, my question is : What is the proper selector to access a root store???

Thanks!

**UPDATE**

This is the best I can do using the createFeatureSelector even if the store is forRoot:

```
const selectStore = createFeatureSelector<TokenState>('security');
export const selectJwt = createSelector(
  selectStore,
  (state: TokenState) => state.keyring.jwt
);
```

Comment: Hmm.. I use a featureSelector to get the root state..?

Comment: @MikeOne : I tried that, it work. But it seems strange to use a method for a Feature store on the root store. Maybe that's the way to go, the documentation is really not clear about that part. So this will work : const test = createFeatureSelector<TokenState>('security');  and export const selectJwt = createSelector(test,(state: TokenState) => state.keyring.jwt);   ... But I"m still wondering if this is the "proper" way do to it?

Answer (score 2):

> But it seems strange to use a method for a Feature store on the root store.

I get the confusion, but `featureSelector` isn't really bound to features it's just there to select a slice from the root object. It's syntactic sugar for `const selectSecurity = (state) => state.security`.

What I tend to use currently (to decrease the complexity) is just use `StoreModule.forRoot({})` to create the store but to not register any reducers.
To register reducers, I'm using `StoreModule.forFeature('security', securityReducer)`.
From my experience this setup is causes less friction for most devs. The outcome of both setups is equal.

Comment: I don't know which version of NgRx your are using (mine is 9.2) but the statement : const selectSecurity = createSelector((state) => state.security)  as no overload available. It expect 2 - 9 arguments. And it was my first attempt was I was looking for the right selector.

Comment: There is no need to use `createSelector` in this case, just: `const selectSecurity = (state: MyState) => state.security`

Comment: This is still not right... state.security is neither part of TokenState or Keyring interface.

Comment: It's part of the global state object. If you don't have a type for it, you'll either have to create one or type it as `any`